# Joining Table with Itself MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a scenario where i have table `app_users` in which i am storing multiple types of users , and each user have different column for `phone number` , and Names , i am trying to get `phone number` and name of specific type of `user` , it's hard to understand this way , but see the working example Query below :

```
SET @sk := (SELECT app_users.skeeper_phone as sphone FROM app_users WHERE app_users. app_user_type = 'SKEEPER' LIMIT 1);
SELECT 
acs.id as complainId,
IF(
    (@sk) > 0,
    @sk,
    ''
) as sk_phone,
(
    SELECT 
    IF(
        auu.institute_phone IS NULL,
        auu.department_phone,
        auu.institute_phone
    ) as cphone
    FROM app_users as auu
    WHERE auu.id = acs.app_customer_id
    LIMIT 1
) as cphone,
(
    SELECT auuu.other_user_phone as ephone
    FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
    WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.engineer_id
    LIMIT 1
) as ephone,
(
    SELECT auuu.fullname as ename
    FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
    WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.engineer_id
    LIMIT 1
) as ename,
(
    SELECT auuu.other_user_phone as ephone
    FROM app_users as auuu,app_admin_assign_eng as aase
    WHERE aase.app_complain_service_id = acs.id AND auuu.id = aase.admin_id
    LIMIT 1
) as aphone
FROM app_complain_services as acs,app_users as au
WHERE 
acs.id = 5
GROUP BY acs.id
```

Above query is working alright , but it is not optimized , what could be optimization and other ways to solve similar problem?

Comment: i think this is a bad table design, why you do this way?

Comment: i'm not the one who designed it , i'm redesigning it